# Perl Variables Only Printing Par of the Stored Data and Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, perl, variables

I have a question about Perl from the script below.  If the input for the `$user` variable is `joeshmo; ls -l;`, perl will only print out joeshmo if the line `print $user` is coded.  My intuition tells me that all of `joeshmo; ls -l;` should be printed.  However, if the user variable is given to finger to be executed, both joeshmo and ls -l are executed.  I ask this because I am trying to limit the input that is allowed to the variable `$user` with a statement like

```
if (($user !~ /^[a-z_A-Z0-9]+[-+%]*[a-z_A-Z0-9]+$/)){
die "The entered user name uses characters not of the alphanumeric form or the \"-\", \"+\", or \"%\"!";
}
else{
```

In the above statement I believe that the only input that will not cause the program to die are statements with alphanumeric characters and an underscore followed by -, +, % characters (if any are desired) and then another round of alphanumeric characters and an underscore.  However, regular expression only evaluates the first part of the `$user` variable and not the entire thing as is the case with the in put `joeshmo; ls -l;`.  The regular expression is only evaluated on joeshmo.

Another interesting piece of information that I do not understand is why the semicolons do not show up when the `$user` variable is printed? If they were, I could just search for those, but they are not printed and thus they are not able to be evaluated on a regular expression.

I would appreciate any help on these matters!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use CGI;
use CGI::Carp qw(fatalsToBrowser);
$q = new CGI;

print $q->header,
    $q->start_html('Finger User'),
    $q->h1('Finger User');
print "<pre>\n";

$user = $q->param("user");
print "\n";
print $user;
print "\n\n";

if (($user !~ /^[a-z_A-Z0-9]+[-+%]*[a-z_A-Z0-9]+$/)){
die "The entered user name uses characters not of the alphanumeric form or the \"-\", \"+\", or \"%\"!";
}
else{
print `/usr/bin/finger -s $user`;
}

print "</pre>";
print $q->end_html;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you're `ls -l` is getting into `$user` at all. If it was, then your regex, which would be better written as `$user !~ /^\w+[-+%]*\w+$/`, would match and your `die` would be executed. I'm guessing that you're calling this script as

```
/cgi-bin/something.pl?user=joeshmo; ls -l;
```

Some implementations allow a semicolon (`;`) to be used as a separator in query strings so that above would be (with some server implementations) equivalent to:

```
/cgi-bin/something.pl?user=joeshmo& ls -l&
```

and so, the `ls -l` part would not be considered part of `user`. Try URL encoding the semicolons and the spaces:

```
/cgi-bin/something.pl?user=joeshmo%3B%20ls%20-l%3B
```

and then you should see your `ls -l` and trigger the `die`.

The reason that `;` is sometimes allowed as a separator is that `&` is also used by HTML for encoding entities, so, any ampersands that appear in an HTML attribute should be encoded as `&amp;` or you're risking confusion; for example, this will often misbehave:

```
<a href="http://example.com?a=b&reg=c">
```

but this won't:

```
<a href="http://example.com?a=b&amp;reg=c">
```

In the [HTML4 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/appendix/notes.html#ampersands-in-uris), the W3 recommends:

> [...] that HTTP server implementors, and in particular, CGI implementors support the use of ";" in place of "&" to save authors the trouble of escaping "&" characters in this manner.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Is this the way semicolons and spaces are sent from an HTML form to the back end CGI script? I ask because that is how the CGI script will be getting the data from the HTML Form.

Comment: @tpar44: The browser *should* take care of properly encoding everything but if you're entering URLs by hand or if you're building links for `<a>` elements by hand, you have to URL encode everything yourself.

Comment: Just too make sure I completely understand what you're saying, if I enter "joeshmo; ls -l;" into a form and click the the button (that sends the "joeshmo; ls -l;" to the backend CGI script) the html form will send "joeshmo; ls -l" as joeshmo%3B%20ls%20-l%3B?

Comment: @tpar44: Right, the form should take care of encoding it and CGI should take care of decoding what the form sends.